# No permitir que el usuario pueda volver al login una ves ingresado al sistema

Tags: android, android-intent

Bueno, tengo una app en Android en la que tengo lo siguiente hasta ahora:
La pantalla de login y una pantalla de "Bienvenido", el punto es que cuando el usuario logra entrar con correo y contraseña correcto lo llevo con un Intent a la pantalla de "Bienvenido", pero al darle en el botón de "atrás" el puede volver a la pantalla de login, cosa que no quiero que pase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regularmente las pantallas de Login o Splash inician un MainActivity dependiendo de la autenticación o ciertas caracteristicas después de permitir la entrada a la aplicación.

Por lo tanto al permitir la entrada a MainActivity finalizas tu pantalla anterior (login o splash) con `finish()`

Ejemplo:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MyActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
//finaliza Login.
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadir en tu fichero `AndroidManifest.xml` el atributo `android:noHistory="true"` en la Actividad a la que no quieres que puedan volver.

Por ejemplo:

```
<activity android:name=".Login" android:noHistory="true"/>
```

Comment: ¿Alguien me puede explicar el porque del voto negativo?